# JsonConvert: Casting to another type only work on the top level

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

**EDIT:** It turns out it isn't tied to the level. It works fine in one class but not the others and I haven't figured out why yet or had the time to further investigate it yet.

I've resorted to something a lill' hacky but very handy to be able to do this in my JSON:

```
"Folder": "path/to/folder"
// or
"Folder": {"Path": "path/to/folder", "ExtraInfo": "..."}
```

They aren't the same type but my `Folder` class contains this:

```
static public explicit operator Folder(string path)
{
    return new Folder(path);
}
```

I then populate my `ScriptableObject` with:

```
Data = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<T>();
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, Data);
```

All works fine until it's further nested into my JSON, and I want to use `Folder` this way:

```
{
    "ComplexData" : [
        {
            "Folders" : [
                 "path/to/A", // Where the magic (the casting) should also happen but doesn't
                 "path/to/B" // Same here
             ]
        },
        { // Error raises here
            "Folders" : []
        }
     ]
}
```

`ComplexData` is a public list of `FolderPack`

```
[System.Serializable]
public class FolderPack
{
    public List<Folder> Folders;
}
```

The error raised:

> JsonSerializationException: Unexpected token when deserializing object: StartObject. Path 'ComplexData[1]', line 14, position 9.

My guess is that `JsonConvert` only handles the first level directly and delegate the deserialization of all further serializable classes. And only it handles casting while others fail with the aforementioned error.

*Note:* A list of `Folders` but on the root level also works just fine.

Comment: built in serialiser is quite basic, but there's several others you can try

Comment: @zambari I'm using JsonConvert, it's not built-in, it's super powerful but I feel like, it's only parsing the root level itself and let the basic one for the rest. (but I might be wrong)

Comment: Can you provide more details about the object being parsed in a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi Will do. Idk when but ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided information the following minimal example was constructed of the models' object graph involved,

```
public class StartObject {
    public List<FolderPack> ComplexData { get; set; }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class FolderPack {
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
}

public class Folder {
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string ExtraInfo { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator Folder(string path) {
        return new Folder(path);
    }

    public Folder() {

    }

    public Folder(string path) {
        this.Path = path;
    }
}
```

Note the use of properties rather than fields. Also the use of an `implicit` operator rather than an `explicit` one.

It was tested and passed as expected.

```
[TestClass]
public class Test {
    [TestMethod]
    public void JsonConvert() {
        var json = @"{
            ""ComplexData"" : [
                {
                    ""Folders"" : [
                         ""path/to/A"",
                         ""path/to/B"" // Same here
                     ]
                },
                {
                    ""Folders"" : []
                }
             ]
        }";
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StartObject>(json);

        result.Should().NotBeNull();
        result.ComplexData[0].Folders[1].Path.Should().Be("path/to/B");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using auto-properties because Unity doesn't serialize them (I'll try to see if it's required for your solution to work or not) and I forgot to mention Folder is also Serializable. As for `implicit` vs `explicit`, I was surprised to see it worked with explicit too and thought I was better off with it then. (Changing it back after my issue raised didn't fix my issue). I'll dig into it and come back to you, cheers.

Comment: @JeromeJ was not aware of the property issue, I tried it again with fields and it still works. Also works for both implicit and explicit. So now it appears that I am unable to reproduce the problem you are having as it works in all the scenarios I use.

Comment: It might be due to the `PopulateObject`?? I'll try providing you a MCV as requested even though your example seemed matching mine.

Comment: @JeromeJ I tested it with populate as well and it works fine. Even removed default constructor from Folder and all tests still pass.